# html button does not go to link when clicked, could be caused by codeigniter 3.0?

Tags: html, codeigniter, ssl

The following html source, from firefox 'view source', does not go to the link when clicked, but when I copy and paste the https URL it works fine.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <p>
            address_name<br>
            NEWaddress<br>
            city&nbsp;,&nbsp;
            state&nbsp;&nbsp;
            postal_code<br>
            country
        </p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://examplesite.com/boxes/buser/edit_address/2">Edit</a>
    </td>           
    <td>$22</td>
</tr>
```

When I right click and inspect element I only see `<td></td>` and I don't see Edit or the link that is in the source.

This happens with a new release of our code switching to codeigniter 3.0.

The codeigniter view that generates the source is

```
<td>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo base_url();?>buser/edit_address/<?php echo $addr->address_id ?>">Edit</a>   
</td>
```

UPDATE: running tests I found this only happens when the page has lots of large images.

Comment: I would `<?php echo base_url('boxes/buser/edit_address/2');?>`

Comment: You also may need to configure you uri routing as well codeigniter guide here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html example `$route['boxes/buser/edit_address/(:any)'] = 'boxes/buser/edit_address/$1'`;

Comment: You also may need to make sure your base_url on config is set for https `$config['base_url'] = 'https://examplesite.com/';`

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was seeing is unrelated to the codeigniter upgrade.  In fact I believe it is unrelated to codeigniter.  The problem is related to having many images on the page.  Further tests indicate that limiting the number of images to 36 400px x 400px images or 100 135px x 136px images fixes the problem.